# Determine MS Exchange server role via WMI and Perl

Tags: perl, wmi, exchange-server

We are working on a project that will require us to determine the exact role of an Exchange server through WMI, using Perl. It looks as if there was a WMI namespace for Exchange that was deprecated some time ago (possibly with 2003?). Is there a way to query through WMI to determine the role of an individual server for Exchange 2007/2010/2013?

Answer (score 1):

No, WMI is not supported in versions of Exchange starting with Exchange 2007. Per [Development technologies for earlier versions of Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877032%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx), the Exchange Management Shell is the recommended replacement for WMI -"Exchange Management Shell commands that work with versions of Exchange starting with Exchange 2007 replace the WMI providers in Exchange 2003. Because Exchange Management Shell commands that enable you to control Exchange servers, storage groups, databases, and users are easier to use than the corresponding WMI providers and objects, you can easily migrate your applications to Exchange Management Shell commands." Hope that helps!